# Problem with having two tasks calling the same action and want only one to be restricted to current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, action

I let users edit their videos and add tags to the videos. Since I set up adding tags as a virtual attribute in the video show view, both tasks hit the same controller method, the videos_controller update method:

```
  def update
    @video = current_user.videos.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @video.update_attributes(params[:video])
        format.html { redirect_to(@video) }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is that I only want the owner of the video to be able to edit their own video, while I want tags to be updated by any user. Is it possible to do this when both tasks hit the same action, or do I need to restructure my app? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your problem in IRC. Give me the points or I will make fun of you elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you would want to make sure you block this in the browser.
It would be confusing for a user to be able to edit stuff and then get an error, because he is not the owner.

Secondly, to protect yourself against tampering, inside your controller you need to do something like:

```
def update
  @video = current_user.videos.find(params[:id])

  video_params = params[:video]
  unless current_user = @video.user_id
    # strip out all harmful parameters
    # this is an example, as i don know 
    video_params.delete(:file_name)

    # maybe here you should do some check if there is anything left?
    # to generate an appropriate error?
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @video.update_attributes(video_params)
      format.html { redirect_to(@video) }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. What is this code protecting me from exactly?

Comment: Hi Justin: if the user is not the owner of the video, it will remove the attributes from the parameters that would update the things only an owner can update. I have no idea which parameters that could be of course, so i guess for instance the `:filename`. If have no idea what parameters you send to the controller. I was assuming a user could update both the tags and the video at the same time (since the code is the same). If the user has no rights: remove the "unallowed" attributes from the received parameters.